# SSMS add-in using Visual Studio 2013

Tags: sql, vb.net, add-in, ssms, visual-studio-addins

So I am trying to make a simple add-in for sql management studio that just formats a simple list. I know what way I am going to achieve this as far as the actual function goes but I am experiencing issues before I even get to start coding! When I redirect the application to open SQL it gives the following message: (I was going to post an image but my rep isn't high enough).

MESSAGE:

> Usage:
>
> > ssme.exe [-S Server_name{\instance_name}}{-d database] [-U user]
> >     [-P password][-E][-nosplash][file_name]*]{-?]

Maybe I am missing a reference to something but I can't see anything at all to do with this.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers.

Comment: I seem to have found the answer. If you remove "/resetaddin" from the command line arguments it seems to fix the problem. (just for future reference to people who experience the same issue)

Comment: How should we create this project type? I can't find "Extensibility->Visual Studio Add-On" in visual studio 2013!

Comment: You have to download the additional project types.

Comment: • Visual studio 2013 sdk (http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=40758)
• Visual studio Installer Projects extension (https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/9abe329c-9bba-44a1-be59-0fbf6151054d)